# Problems in powering off ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

When I want to turn off my laptop It doesn't power off. The screen power off, but the laptop still making noise, and the work indicator is on. It powers off when the battery becomes empty. I don't know what to do. Can't you help me?

- Manufacturer: HP
- Product Name: HP Laptop 15-bw0xx
- Processor: AMD® A12-9720p radeon r7, 12 compute cores 4c+8g × 4
- Graphics: AMD® Radeon (tm) r7 m340 / AMD® Radeon r7 graphics
- OS name: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- SSD: 256,1 GB
- RAM: 7,2 GiB

`sudo shutdown now`, `poweroff -p` and `systemctl poweroff` doesn't help me. The laptop still doesn't power off.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer? This will help identify if it’s a known issue. If there is any error message or text on the screen when the notebook is shutting down, knowing what it says will also help 

Comment: As above and, to the best of your knowledge, please post detailed hardware specifications so we don't have to google about it.

Comment: when I turn off the laptop no error messages is displayed

Comment: Can you report if opening a terminal and typing `sudo shutdown now` (and your user password when prompted) does a complete power down?

Comment: Oh, and be sure to take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] -- that will help you understand why more details are helpful.  Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: `sudo shutdown now` doesn't help me. The laptop still doesn't power off.

Comment: Now, please [edit] that into the question -- comments aren't permanent.  It will probably help someone who knows more "under the hood" about the shutdown process than I do.

Comment: Did you try `poweroff -p` or `systemctl poweroff`?

Comment: Have you tried just letting the Battery run out?

Answer (score 1):

You can shut down from the command line (terminal) you will need to be root to do this;

```
sudo -i
shutdown -h now
```

sudo -i - changes you to the root user, you may be asked to confirm your password.

shutdown -h now - this issues the halt command 'now' which should cause the OS to go through the shutdown process. See https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown

If there is a problem, you should see output on the terminal window, and in /var/log/syslog

If you are not able to shutdown in the GUI, possibly your user does not have permission, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85663/poweroff-or-reboot-as-normal-user

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it was due to the Linux kernel upgrade to version 5.11.0-41.

You can try and confirm if that's the problem by booting to an older kernel version (5.11.0-40) in `Advanced Options` of GRUB.

If that is the case, you can definitely fix it by downgrading to version 5.11.0-40:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic
```

And then reboot.